# Transaction null even after getting mined

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mining

I am invoking a smartContract method to issue coin(cryptocurrency example). When I invoke the method the transaction is getting submitted and mined. refer the below transaction logs. But after that when I check the Txreceipt the value is returned as null.

```
I1129 08:55:48.861202 eth/api.go:1193] Tx(0xb916c58007f51cc7040a3ac52515fb9ae674e533c9093862417a3ae7bffeeff2) to: 0x4745e9013ede7928f7ac2068c396a164e033edf2
== Pending transactions! Mining...
I1129 08:55:49.067910 miner/miner.go:119] Starting mining operation (CPU=1 TOT=2)
I1129 08:55:49.070917 miner/worker.go:573] commit new work on block 139 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 2.0061ms
I1129 08:55:50.988262 miner/worker.go:339] ??  Mined block (#139 / de47fd54). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I1129 08:55:50.988262 miner/worker.go:573] commit new work on block 140 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 0
I1129 08:55:50.989263 miner/worker.go:435] ?? ??  Mined 5 blocks back: block #134
I1129 08:55:50.992266 miner/worker.go:573] commit new work on block 140 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 1.0031ms
== No transactions! Mining stopped.
```